# How to use c# singleton class in Orchard Themes

Tags: c#, themes, orchardcms

I'm using Orchard to build my website and want to add different elements for production environment and test environemnt in the Themes. I tried to use a c# singleton class in Orchard Themes class to get if it is production environment. Then use the singleton class in the cshtml file in Themes. The code can be compiled. But in run time, it will throw exception saying:The name 'Themes' does not exist in the current context. I have to add "Themes" namespace before the class I added. Otherwise, it won't pass compile.

Details: 
I added a singleton class: EnvironmentDev.cs file into Themes.csproj file. It contains static GetInstance method and IsProd property. 
In Themes.csproj file, it shows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="EnvironmentDev.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In Document.cshtml file of Themes, I added following code:

```
@{
    if (Themes.EnvironmentDev.GetInstance().IsProd) {
        // Add production element
    }
    else {
        // Add test site element
    }
}
```

Detailed Error message:
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Themes' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

```
Line 46:     @Display(Model.Head)
Line 47:     @{
Line 48:         if (Themes.EnvironmentDev.GetInstance().IsProd) {
Line 49:             <script src="https://XXXX.js"></script> //using XXXX instead of real link
Line 50:         }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a dedicated project for your theme with the following command

```
codegen theme MyTheme /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true
```

otherwise your code will not be found. I had the same issue with a resource file.

See paragraph **Generating the Theme Structure** in the [docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme) for further information.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!